# Is it possible to make dropdown boxes from left join data?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently working on a search module where the user chooses a car brand from the database in a dropdown menu and can then choose a model and motortype in seperate dropdown boxes aswell.

My question is, how do i make it possible to use data from a left join in a dropdown box?

This is my code so far, for reference:

```
//Connect to our MySQL database using the PDO extension.
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');

//Our select statement. This will retrieve the data that we want.
$sql =  "SELECT brands.BrandID, brands.Brands, models.ModelID, models.Models, type.TypeID, type.Type
        FROM onderdelen
        LEFT JOIN brands ON brands.Merknaam = onderdelen.Merknaam
        LEFT JOIN models ON models.Merknaam = onderdelen.Merknaam
        LEFT JOIN type ON type.Merknaam = onderdelen.Merknaam";



//Prepare the select statement.
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

//Execute the statement.
$stmt->execute();

//Retrieve the rows using fetchAll.
$cars = $stmt->fetchAll();

?>
```

Comment: You don't know how to parse the return into HTML elements? Show us what you're returning from the query.

Comment: There are so many tutorials that do EXACTLY this!